# Stripe: How to simulate the life cycle of a recurring subscription via CLI

Tags: stripe-payments

I have active subscription, and I need simulate

1. normal recurring payment
2. failure recurring payment for example 2 times
   I have set up in (Manage failed payments) 2 times (Retry 1 day after the previous attempt)
3. If all retries for a payment fail,

how can I do it?
or can I use another solution for testing?

I have web hook listener, and I listen on:

`invoice.payment_succeeded`: normal subscription renewal and sending the client an email about it

`invoice.payment_failed`: the failure to pay and sending the client an email about it

`customer.subscription.deleted`: If all retries for a payment fail stop subscription for client and sending the client an email about it

Answer (score 2):

You can simulate Billing events (such as successful and failing recurring payments) using [test clocks](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/testing/test-clocks).